# How to index Javascript Array from JSON Data?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I made a simple JavaScript project using AngularJS,

Here's my controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('BillDetail3Ctrl', function ($scope, billDetail3) { 

    $scope.tableData = [];
    $scope.hourCount = 0; 

    billDetail3.getMetList().then(function(data){    

        var no = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j == data[0].d.currA.length; j++) {
                $scope.tableData.push({
                    'No': ++no,
                    '_id': data[i]._id,
                    'hourtag': data[i].d.hourtag,  
                    'currA': data[i].d.currA[j]  
                }); 
            }
        }

        $scope.hourCount = no;
    }, function(){

    });
  });
```

Those controller was fetching data from this JSON: http://amr2.mybluemix.net/getmet/list
This is the format of JSON:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "100010001_20082015_0",
    "_rev": "8-e72619f2c6c05aac2e3692f1ea77eb0f",
    "d": {
      "uSN": "100010001",
      "timetag": 20082015,
      "hourtag": 0,
      "currA": {
        "0": 0,
        "1": 2,
        "2": 5,
        "3": 6,
        "4": 2.3
      },
      "currB": {
        "0": 10,
        "1": 23,
        "2": 52,
        "3": 61,
        "4": 12.3
      },
      "currABC": {
        "0": 0.1,
        "1": 2.2,
        "2": 5.2
      },
```

Here's my view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pop in tableData">
       <td>{{pop.No}}</td>
       <td>{{pop._id}}</td>
       <td>{{pop.hourtag}}</td>
       <td>{{pop.currA}}</td>  //This is doesn't work
 </tr>
```

But this code `<td>{{pop.currA}}</td>` doesn't work. So, in JSON I have `hourtag = 0, hourtag = 1, etc.` In each hourtag, I have `"currA": { "0": x, "1" = x, etc.` The idea was I want to call all of the currA value which is in the first `"0"` in every hourtag and put that in my table. How can I do that?

Here's the conclusion
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Should it be something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/1033/ (simplified example)

The key change is in for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var curHourtag = data[i].d.hourtag;
    $scope.tableData.push({
        'No': ++no,
        '_id': data[i]._id,
        'hourtag': curHourtag,
        'currA': data[i].d.currA[curHourtag]
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, little bit closer mate. The hourtag was showing the right result, but currA still showing 1 right result. the others incorrect. in each hourtag I want to show the result from it's currA[0]. Please see my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/liverpool06/rLnj7yn7/

Comment: In your fiddle Angular is not active ? Here is same code with angular engaged: https://jsfiddle.net/rLnj7yn7/1/

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate it. I modified your code a bit and it works.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
Thanks for @Dfr answer, I modified `'currA': data[i].d.currA[curHourtag]` line to `'currA': data[i].d.currA[0]` and it works fine as I expected.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var curHourtag = data[i].d.hourtag;
    $scope.tableData.push({
        'No': ++no,
        '_id': data[i]._id,
        'hourtag': curHourtag,
        'currA': data[i].d.currA[0]
    }); 
}
```